# What's the bs-css child selector equivalent of sass child selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, reason, glamor, bs-css

I currently have some SASS I'm trying to convert to use `bs-css` (7.3).

The sass looks like

```
.checkbox {
    svg {
        height: 28px;
        width: 28px;
    }
}
```

I've tried using

```
open Css;
let checkbox =
    style([
    backgroundColor(Basics.Colors.white),
    border(`px(1), `solid, Basics.Colors.gray850),
    selector(
        "svg",
        [height(Basics.Icon.epsilon), width(Basics.Icon.epsilon)],
    ),
    ]);
```

But I get back the css property `svg` set to `[Object Object]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bs-css](/questions/tagged/bs-css) is basically bindings to [glamor](/questions/tagged/glamor), so you can use any selector described [in its docs](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor/blob/master/docs/howto.md).

For [child selectors](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor/blob/master/docs/howto.md#child-selectors) it recommends using `"& svg"`, and although the `&` can be omitted, I'd really recommend including it for readability. Whitespace tends to be easy to miss.